# Get drive label in C#

Tags: c#, drive

When I use `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()` and look at the `.VolumeLabel` property of one of the drives, I see "PATRIOT XT", which is indeed the drive's volume label.

If I open "My Computer", instead I see "TrueCrypt Traveler Disk", and I can't seem to find any way to programmatically retrieve that value as none of the `DriveInfo` properties hold that value. I also tried querying the information via WMI's `Win32_LogicalDisk`, but no properties contained that value there either.

So any idea what the label My Computer uses is called, and more importantly, how to programmatically retrieve it?

EDIT: To be clear, here's the code I'm using, followed by what it outputs, followed by what I see in My Computer (which is what I want to duplicate):

```
foreach (DriveInfo DI in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    richTextBox1.AppendText(
        (
            DI.IsReady ?
            (DI.VolumeLabel.Length == 0 ? DI.DriveType.ToString() : DI.VolumeLabel) :
            DI.DriveType.ToString()
        )
        +
        " (" + DI.Name.Replace("\\", "") + ")"
        + Environment.NewLine
    );
```

```
Removable (A:)
Fixed (C:)
CDRom (D:)
PATRIOT XT (E:)
Backup (Y:)
Data (Z:)
```

My Computer details view displays:

```
Floppy Disk Drive (A:)
Local Disk (C:)
DVD RW Drive (D:)
TrueCrypt Traveler Disk (E:)
Backup (Y:)
Data (Z:)
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, to get this information without hacks and weird tricks, you need to use the P/Invoke technique.
There are 2 options:

1. Get the real label set by user or system. This could be "*New volume*", "*Install (\Server)*", "*Contoso Pro Installation disk 4*" and so on.
2. Get the label exactly as it is shown in Explorer (My computer / This PC window). This is the same as (1) but it follows user preferences set in Folder Options dialog, e.g. "Hide drive letter". Example: "*New volume (Q:)*"

To get the information as explained in option (1), you'll have to use the following code:

```
    public const string SHELL = "shell32.dll";

    [DllImport(SHELL, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern uint SHParseDisplayName(string pszName, IntPtr zero, [Out] out IntPtr ppidl, uint sfgaoIn, [Out] out uint psfgaoOut);
    
    [DllImport(SHELL, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern uint SHGetNameFromIDList(IntPtr pidl, SIGDN sigdnName, [Out] out String ppszName);
    
    public enum SIGDN : uint
    {
        NORMALDISPLAY = 0x00000000,
        PARENTRELATIVEPARSING = 0x80018001,
        DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING = 0x80028000,
        PARENTRELATIVEEDITING = 0x80031001,
        DESKTOPABSOLUTEEDITING = 0x8004c000,
        FILESYSPATH = 0x80058000,
        URL = 0x80068000,
        PARENTRELATIVEFORADDRESSBAR = 0x8007c001,
        PARENTRELATIVE = 0x80080001
    }
    
    //var x = GetDriveLabel(@"C:\")
    public string GetDriveLabel(string driveNameAsLetterColonBackslash)
    {
        IntPtr pidl;
        uint dummy;
        string name;
        if (SHParseDisplayName(driveNameAsLetterColonBackslash, IntPtr.Zero, out pidl, 0, out dummy) == 0
            && SHGetNameFromIDList(pidl, SIGDN.PARENTRELATIVEEDITING, out name) == 0
            && name != null)
        {
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

For option (2), replace `SIGDN.PARENTRELATIVEEDITING` with `SIGDN.PARENTRELATIVE` or `SIGDN.NORMALDISPLAY`.

**Note**: for option 2, there's also 1-call method using `ShGetFileInfo()`, but it calls these methods anyway, and is less flexible, so I do not post it here.

**Note 2**: keep in mind, the signature of `SHGetNameFromIDList()` is optimized in this example. In case the drive label is used only temporary (especially if it is re-read from time to time) this example introduces small memory leak. To avoid it, declare last parameter as `out IntPtr`, and then use something like

```
     var tmp = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ppszName);
     Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppszName);
```

**Note 3**: this works over Windows shell, so it will return what user expects, regardless of the source of this label - volume label, user edit, Autorun.inf file or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for tip about autorun.inf.  Here is the C# fragment which I created to retrieve the label.

```
private string GetDriveLabelFromAutorunInf(string drivename)
    {
        try
        {
            string filepathAutorunInf = Path.Combine(drivename, "autorun.Inf");
            string stringInputLine = "";
            if (File.Exists(filepathAutorunInf))
            {
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filepathAutorunInf);
                while ((stringInputLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) 
                  {
                      if (stringInputLine.StartsWith("label="))
                          return stringInputLine.Substring(startIndex:6);
                  }
                return "";
            }
            else return "";
        }
        #region generic catch exception, display message box, and terminate
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(exception, true);
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Exception:\n{1}\n{2}\n\n{3}\n\nMethod={4}   Line={5}   Column={6}",
                    trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Module,
                    exception.Message,
                    exception.StackTrace,
                    exception.ToString(),
                    trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name,
                    trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(),
                    trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileColumnNumber()),
                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Environment.Exit(1);
            return "";      // to keep compiler happy
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like My Computer looks at the autorun.inf and uses the label= value from the [autorun] section.

Still not quite sure where the "DVD RW Drive" and "Floppy Disk Drive" labels come from, but I guess they may be hardcoded based on the drive type.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following will help you:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool GetVolumeInformation(string Volume,
        StringBuilder VolumeName, uint VolumeNameSize,
        out uint SerialNumber, out uint SerialNumberLength, out uint flags,
        StringBuilder fs, uint fs_size);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uint serialNum, serialNumLength, flags;
        StringBuilder volumename = new StringBuilder(256);
        StringBuilder fstype = new StringBuilder(256);
        bool ok = false;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        foreach (string drives in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())
        {
            ok = GetVolumeInformation(drives, volumename, (uint)volumename.Capacity - 1, out serialNum,
                                   out serialNumLength, out flags, fstype, (uint)fstype.Capacity - 1);
            if (ok)
            {
                lblVolume.Text = lblVolume.Text + "\n Volume Information of " + drives + "\n";
                lblVolume.Text = lblVolume.Text + "\nSerialNumber of is..... " + serialNum.ToString() + " \n";
                if (volumename != null)
                {
                    lblVolume.Text = lblVolume.Text + "VolumeName is..... " + volumename.ToString() + " \n";
                }
                if (fstype != null)
                {
                    lblVolume.Text = lblVolume.Text + "FileType is..... " + fstype.ToString() + " \n";
                }
            }
            ok = false;
        }
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Comment: This code is bad in general and does not show what the OP wants to see. This information is much easier obtained from `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried [this](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/912/) myself, but in the registry, look for

```
HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/DriveIcons/[Drive-Letter]/
```

then read the

```
DefaultLabel
```

key. Also **WARNING!** writing invalid keys/values to the registry can severely damage your system! Be sure you're certain of what you're doing before proceeding. [Here is a resource to help you with accessing the registry programmatically.](http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/01/registry-ins-and-outs-using-c/)

Comment: What OS do you have? There is no key named "DriveIcons" in Win XP Home!!

Comment: @Nayan - I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: I thought the value might be in the registry so already searched for "TrueCrypt Traveler Disk", and found it in:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\{73716ff9-140f-11df-b2ee-0018f30639c7}\_Autorun\DefaultLabel

So I might have been able to retrieve the value if it was in the location you indicated, but the GUID in the location I found it in makes things problematic.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/246182-c-net-volume-label) looks like it could be a solution.

Comment: Thanks, but Win32_DiskDrive and Win32_PhysicalMedia don't seem to hold the values I'm looking for either.  I've tried several of the Win32 classes now, and none of them seem to!

Answer (score 0):

It's located in the autorun.inf folder. My Volume Label for my flash drive is simply 16G,
but by putting an autorun.inf file with the following text
[autorun]
label=My 16 gigabyte Flash Drive

and then using attrib to +s +h +r the file, it doesn't show up unless I have
show hidden files AND show system files under folder options/view enabled.

To programmatically located this via C#, I honestly haven't tried to open the autorun.inf,
but it should be straight forward, check if File.Exists(Drive:\autorun.inf) ignoring
the fact that it's +s+h+r (just in case someone has set it), then open it readonly
and parse the label= line.  If in fact, the file is present, use the autorun label instead of
the Volume Label.

I can still change use the autorun.inf label= tag even in Windows 7 to modify label.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem that I have been able to solve. Here is how to obtain the labels as they appear in the Windows Explorer:

1. Add `C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll` as a reference.
2. Add `using Shell32;`
3. Instantiate the shell object:
   `dynamic shellObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));`
4. Get the disk data: `var driveData = (Folder2)ShellObject.NameSpace(driveInfo.Name);`
5. The parameter `driveData.Name` will contain the label (For example: "Local Disk (C:)").

And below is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Shell32;

namespace VolumeLabels
{
    static class Drives
    {
        [DebuggerDisplay("Name: '{Name,nq}', Path: '{Path,nq}'")]
        public struct DriveNameInfo
        {
            public string Name { get; }
            public string Path { get; }

            public DriveNameInfo(string name, string path)
            {
                Name = name;
                Path = path;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Name;
            }
        }

        private static dynamic _shellObject;
        private static dynamic ShellObject => _shellObject ?? (_shellObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application")));

        public static IEnumerable<DriveNameInfo> Get()
        {
            foreach (var driveInfo in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                var driveData = (Folder2)ShellObject.NameSpace(driveInfo.Name);
                if (driveData == null)
                    yield break;
                var driveDataSelf = driveData.Self;

                yield return new DriveNameInfo(driveDataSelf.Name, driveDataSelf.Path);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var driveNameInfo in Drives.Get())
                Console.WriteLine(driveNameInfo);

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```