# c# how to get a file path of the same file on different computers

Tags: c#, winforms, path

i am trying to make a code which takes an image from a file path which i type in manually.
here is my code:

`pieceImage = Image.FromFile(@"O:\Projects\imagename.png");`

This code is saved on my USB flash drive.
However, whenever i run this code on a different computer, the path is different (obviously) and doesn't necessarily start with O:\ but something else, for example F:.

What can i use so that the path will change accordingly to the computer on which it runs? many thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps you can look at how to map a folder.. not all computers will have the same drive names

Comment: thats impossible because those computers can have different drive names. you should first copy that image file  nearer to the project folder in the other computer so that you can use Relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the drive letter based on the drive name, then build the Path to the file based on that (so only use the relative path from the root of the drive, no letter). See the [DriveInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) on MSDN and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843935/get-drive-label-in-c-sharp) for a practical example of usage.

Of course, if the image is not on the USB drive, you will need to be more creative. But then I would recommand a different approach all the same, because there might be a design flaw in all this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your program is in directory /Program/, include all images under your /Program/ directory, such as /Program/Images/. That way the images will be available no matter where the program is run.