# Get Correct Drive Name

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to obtain the name of a mapped network drive but everything I've tried comes back with the incorrect data.

On my work PC I have 5 drives.

```
C:\  which is displayed in Computer as OS (C:)
D:\  which is displayed in Computer as DVD RW Drive (D:) when no CD or DVD is in the drive.
T:\  which is displayed in Computer as IT--- (\\Homedrive) (T:)
V:\  which is displayed in Computer as Ste Moore (\\Homedrive\IT) (V:)
Z:\  which is displayed in Computer as dg.net (\\dg) (Z:)
```

When I use System.IO.DriveInfo to get the drive details, the Volume Label for the drives is as follows

```
C:\   OS
D:\   Nothing as it is not ready
T:\   IT
V:\   IT
Z:\   DGNET
```

I understand that T:\ shows as IT--- because it was renamed, but none of the others have.

Is there any way to get the name that is displayed in Computer, This Computer,  My Computer or This PC?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `DriveInfo.Name` to get the name and `DriveInfo.DriveType` to get the type

Comment: You should show us the code you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get drive label in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843935/get-drive-label-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Pikoh, I didn't think I would need to. I thought that saying "When I use System.IO.DriveInfo to get the drive details, the Volume Label for the drives is as follows"  would have explained what I've done.  If you need to see the exact code it is Dim _DriveName as String = New DriveInfo("T:\").VolumeLabel.  GSerg, I'll take a look at your link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks GSerg, your link provided the answer, even though it was in C#.

For anyone else looking for this information who doesn't know C#, here it is in VB.Net

```
<DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Shared Function SHParseDisplayName(pszName As String, zero As IntPtr, <Out> ByRef ppidl As IntPtr, sfgaoIn As UInteger, <Out> ByRef psfgaoOut As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function

<DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Shared Function SHGetNameFromIDList(pidl As IntPtr, sigdnName As SIGDN, <Out> ByRef ppszName As [String]) As UInteger
End Function

Public Enum SIGDN As UInteger
    NORMALDISPLAY = &H0
    PARENTRELATIVEPARSING = &H80018001UI
    DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING = &H80028000UI
    PARENTRELATIVEEDITING = &H80031001UI
    DESKTOPABSOLUTEEDITING = &H8004C000UI
    FILESYSPATH = &H80058000UI
    URL = &H80068000UI
    PARENTRELATIVEFORADDRESSBAR = &H8007C001UI
    PARENTRELATIVE = &H80080001UI
End Enum

Public Function GetDriveLabel(driveNameAsLetterColonBackslash As String) As String
    Dim pidl As IntPtr = Nothing
    Dim dummy As UInteger = Nothing
    Dim name As String = Nothing

    If SHParseDisplayName(driveNameAsLetterColonBackslash, IntPtr.Zero, pidl, 0, dummy) = 0 AndAlso
       SHGetNameFromIDList(pidl, SIGDN.PARENTRELATIVEEDITING, name) = 0 AndAlso Not name Is Nothing Then
        Return name
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```